C++ Compilation on Mac M2: error: 'value' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.13
When trying to install fairseq using pip, I run into the following error:
error: 'value' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.13
          return shared_view_info_ ? backward_info_.value() : forward_info_.value();
                                                    ^

This is the output of gcc --version:
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.1.0

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance for your help!
I read in C++ Compilation on Mac M3: error: 'value' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.13 that introducing -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 into the compiler and linker command can fix this, but I'm not sure how exactly to do that given that this is getting kicked off by a pip install command.

See linked duplicate, except you want to set CXXFLAGS

Thanks for the response! I set CXXFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.13", ran pip install fairseq, and still encountered the issue. Did I set the flag incorrectly?
